# Expect Script grep and awk output to be used as variable

Tags: unix, awk, grep, expect

I have looked and don't see a question quite like this one.
I have an expect script that logs into remote systems and can send commands.
I have a special case where I need to send a command based on the output of the previous command.

I log the session of every host I log into to a file so my game plan was to possibly grep that log file for the value I need so I can then pass it to the next several commands.

For instance.
SSH to device.
Send a command that would result with a string in $this_host.log:
returns instance: 541  ( have ommitted part of the output on purpose)
In shell you could just get the 541 part by doing the following:
grep "returns instance" *.log | awk '{ print $7 }'

In expect I would like to store that 541 value to a variable so that I could then do a:
send "next.command.$value"  where value equals 541.  541 is just an example as it could be any 3 digit number there.

I'm not sure how to convert that grep | awk combo to expect format. 
I use these combos all the time in regular shell scripts: for example
UPTIME="$(grep -E "System Uptime: " $log | awk '{ print $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 }')"

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. You're already in expect: expect automates the interactive session: you can capture the output of the commands you send.

An example: you are connected to a remote system, and you want to send the `date` command. Your prompt is the hostname followed by  `$` followed by a space. Visually, you would see this:

```
host$ date
Wed Dec 12 20:48:57 EST 2018
host$
```

In expect you would do this:

```
expect -re {\$ $}
send "date\r"
expect -re {(.+)\$ $}
```

At this point, `$expect_out(1,string)` contains this text: `date\r\nWed Dec 12 20:48:57 EST 2018\r\nhost`. It's a bit of a pain that you get the command and also the start of the prompt, but with Tcl string handling, we can fairly easily handle it:

```
set lines [split $expect_out(1,string) \n]
set no_cr [lmap line $lines {string {map "\r" ""} $line}]
set command_out [join [lrange $no_cr 1 end-1] \n]
```